# Connecting remote search results with local database using CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, core-data

Assume we have simple data model with single entity `User`; simple `tableView_friends` with `fetchedResultsController_friends` for show users - friends.

Assume we have search bar for searching *all* (not only friends) users in service, and for every typed in it character we perform search request to server, which return to us somehow filtered by character User objects. Some of this objects can already be inside local database. By app logic we don't really *must* save all this results in local database forever (but ok, we can, we can clear local database time to time); on other hand, if we will perform any action on some searched user, we must store this user. We want to show list of searched user in other `tableView_search` with `fetchedResultsController_search`.

**Question:** should I use same context for `fetchedResultsController_friends` and `fetchedResultsController_search`? If no, how can I handle situation, when I wish to edit searched user, which already exists in database and probably already local edited? If yes, how can I setup predicate for `fetchedResultsController_search` (server perform its own logic for search by character, which can be changed) for show exactly same result as from server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently implemented a search feature in our application and had a similar issue, We had local data in core data and also remote data from our API.

You have a few options that we explored:

1. Save your data into core data from the API as it is retreived and
   then the fetched results controller will do the rest
2. Manage the merge of the data yourself, you can still use NSFetchedResults controller to an extent but need to do more work

We didn't want to save all of the information returned from the API unless it was needed (the user selected it), so we come up with a simple solution that worked for our app. This may not work directly for your app, you may need a completely different solution or change some of the things we done to suit.

Firstly, To explain what we are dealing with, we had a Article entity in core data which contains around 25 properties, the API returns article objects as JSON data with the same data.

What we decided to do was to create a class which represents a simple version of an article (just enough data to show in a list view and reference it later in the API or core data) which looked something like this:

```
class SearchResult: NSObject {

    var id:String?
    var title:String?
    var imageUrl:String?
    var url:String?

    // core data entity
    init(article:Article) {
        self.id = content.contentId
        self.title = content.title
        self.featuredImageURL = content.absoluteImagePath()
        self.urlAlias = content.urlAlias
        self.publishedAt = content.publishedAt
    }

    init(articleDictionary:NSDictionary) {
        self.id = articleDictionary.objectForKeyNotNull("id") as? String
        self.title = articleDictionary.objectForKeyNotNull("title") as? String
        self.url = articleDictionary.objectForKeyNotNull("url") as? String

        if let imageUrl = articleDictionary.objectForKeyNotNull("imageUrl") as? String {
            self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        }
    }
}
```

Now using this, we can create once of these from either the core data results or from the API results. Our tableview datasource is just an array

```
var dataSet = [SearchResult]()
```

We use the NSFectchResultsController delegate methods to add/remove/re-order core data elements from the dataSet after the initial load and when we get API data we'll do something like:

```
dataSet = Array(Set(apiResponseArray + dataSet))
```

This will take an array of SearchResult items from the API, merge them with the current result set and remove duplicates. casting to a set and then back to an array will give you an array of unique results as a Set is made of unique values only.

See this [reference](https://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) which should help with how the  delegate methods would work

Comment: Thank you for great answer! Im I right that you keep search method on server clear and predicate in app for local database work exactly same? Did you receive all data from server for search request in one step or by pieces? Am I right in thinking that if I will scroll to 25.000 row, then `dataSet.count` will be >= 25.000?

Comment: we paginate our remote API search results, so that we receive around 20 at a time and  can scroll for as many as we want. if you are searching local content and remote data you should really ensre the search is roughly the same to get relevant results. if you scroll to a row of 25k then yes, your count would likely be 25k becuase its unlikely you'll have any local content that doesnt exist on the server.

Comment: let me imagine that you have articles with titles _aaa_ and _azz_, stored in local database, and you perform remote search for key "a". Does it means, that after every request (until you will get once _azz_ article from server) you will always have article _azz_ at last row in your `tableView`? I mean something like this in  `tableView`: **firstRequest**: _aaa_, _aab_, _aac_, ..., _aay_, _azz_; **secondRequest**: _aaa_, _aab_, _aac_, ..., _aay_, _aaz_, _aba_, _abb_, ..., _abx_, _azz_

Comment: it depends on your implementation, we sort our content by its published date